# Modify EXIF/IPTC info in .dng (rawfiles) via Python?

Tags: python, exif, rtc, iptc, dng

Anyone aware of some Python module or library capable of modifying EXIF and IPTC data in Adobe RAW files (.dng)? Until some eight years ago, I used JPEG and could rather easily do such modifications helped by Python. After having switched to RAW, I have to use image tools to modify EXIF info.

Primarily the EXIF Taken date is of interest to be modified, but some IPTC-fields are also candidates of modification.

(I'm geotagging photos from my cameras each of which have RTC's that creeps in various directions and amounts. My 'worst' camera 'hurries' ~2.4 sec per day. Before matching photodates with .gpx-data from a GPS-logger, I need to modify the Taken date with various amounts depending on number of days since cameraclocksetting.)

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects I use GExiv2 (https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2) with the PyGObject bindings (https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject). GExiv2 is a wrapper around exiv2, which can read & write Exif, IPTC and XMP metadata in DNG files: http://www.exiv2.org/manpage.html

Comment: can you give an example of how to write tags to a DNG file with the tools you mention?

Comment: You could try the exiv2 examples: www.exiv2.org/sample.html

Comment: The problem is not with exiv2 but with GExiv2 and PyGObject, I don't know how to use them